# reverse list and issues with adding

Tags: python, list, queue

I'm attempting to make a Queue and my first issue is that my output is printing the "contents" section in reverse order (i.e. "Contents: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1" instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

I'm also having an issue with a part later in the main section where I have Numbers += 15, and the queue is supposed to then be 10-15, but I have no clue how to do that

```
 class Queue:
     def __init__(self, items):
         self.items = []

     def is_empty(self):
         return self.items == []

     def enqueue(self, item):
         self.items.insert(0, item)

     def __repr__(self):
    return "Contents: {}".format(str(self.items).strip("[]"))

     def dequeue(self):
         return self.items.pop()

     def size(self):
         return len(self.items)

 # -----------------------------------------------------

 def main():
     numbers = Queue("Numbers")

     print("Enqueue 1, 2, 3, 4, 5")
     print("---------------------")
     for number in range(1, 6):
         numbers.enqueue(number)
         print(numbers)

     print("\nDequeue one item")
     print("----------------")
     numbers.dequeue()
     print(numbers)

     print("\nDeque all items")
     print("---------------")
     while not numbers.is_empty():
         print("Item dequeued:", numbers.dequeue())
         print(numbers)

     # Enqueue 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
     for number in range(10, 15):
         numbers.enqueue(number)

     # Enqueue 15
     numbers += 15

     print("\n10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 enqueued")
     print("-------------------------------")
     print(numbers)

 # -----------------------------------------------------

 main()
```

Comment: What is the point of the argument to `__init__`?  You just discard it.  So either use it, or get rid of it.

Comment: You `enqueue` method inserts values at the beginning of your list, this will reverse any values "enqued". For example: enqueue(1) > [1]: enqueue(2) > [2, 1], etc

Answer (score 0):

With the following code:

```
print("Enqueue 1, 2, 3, 4, 5")
print("---------------------")
for number in range(1, 6):
    numbers.enqueue(number)
```

you are adding the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 to the data structure. Due to the implementation of `enqueue`, each number is added to the start of the list (index zero):

```
def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.insert(0, item)
```

I.e., after having inserted 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, you have a list containing `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

If you want each number to be added to the end of `items`, you should change the method to:

```
def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)
```

Which will make it print this instead:

```
Enqueue 1, 2, 3, 4, 5                                                                 
---------------------                                                                 
Contents: 1                                                                           
Contents: 1, 2                                                                        
Contents: 1, 2, 3                                                                     
Contents: 1, 2, 3, 4                                                                  
Contents: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Furthermore, to enqueue `15` to the data structure. Change:

```
    # Enqueue 15
    numbers += 15
```

to:

```
    # Enqueue 15
    numbers.enqueue(15)
```